# EXCEL 2016 VBA: Swapping the Primary and Secondary Y Axes

Tags: excel, vba, graph

I am attempting to programmatically generate a histogram with a normal curve superimposed on it. The general strategy that I gleaned from various help pages and posts is to create a xlXYScatterSmoothNoMarkers, add a data series for the x and y values for the normal curve, and then add my histogram data (breaks and freqs) as another data series, and then change the histogram data series to xlColumnClustered, and do some final formatting. However, when I get near the end, the density values for the normal curve are on the primary Y axis and the frequency values are on the secondary Y axis. I am looking for a method to switch them. Here is a pic of the graph so far:

[Screen shot of Graph So Far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WR7KL.png)

Here is my code as of right now:

===

```
Set MyChart = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Add(Left:=Cells(Row0 + (j3 - 1) * 22, Col0 + ChartStart + 1 + (k3 - 1) * 7).Left, _
                    Top:=Cells(Row0 + (j3 - 1) * 22, Col0 + ChartStart + 1 + (k3 - 1) * 7).Top, _
                    Width:=350, _
                    Height:=300).Chart
        
                MyChart.ChartType = xlXYScatterSmoothNoMarkers
                MyChart.HasLegend = False


        With MyChart
                    'XAxis Label
                    .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
                    .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "Model Residuals"
                    .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Font.Bold = True
                    .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Font.Name = "TimesNewRoman"
                    .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Font.Size = 10
                    .Axes(xlCategory).TickLabelPosition = xlTickLabelPositionLow
                    'YAxis Label
                    .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
                    .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "Frequency"
                    .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Font.Bold = True
                    .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Font.Name = "TimesNewRoman"
                    .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Font.Size = 10
                    'Format Bars
                    '.ChartGroups(1).GapWidth = 0
                    '.ChartGroups(1).Overlap = 100
                End With
                    
                'Remove Gridlines
                For Each axs In MyChart.Axes
                    axs.HasMajorGridlines = False
                    axs.HasMinorGridlines = False
                Next
                
                With MyChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
                    .Values = NormCurve
                    .XValues = XGraph
                    'Format
                End With
                
                'New X Axis Limits
                'MyChart.Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).MinimumScale = WorksheetFunction.Floor(XGraph(1), 100)
                'MyChart.Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).MaximumScale = WorksheetFunction.Ceiling(XGraph((ZMax - ZMin) * 100 + 1), 100)
                
                
                ReDim XLim(1 To 2)
                ReDim YLim(1 To 2)
                'MyChart.Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).MinimumScale = XGraph(1)
                'MyChart.Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).MaximumScale = XGraph((ZMax - ZMin) * 100 + 1)
                XLim(1) = MyChart.Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).MinimumScale
                XLim(2) = MyChart.Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).MaximumScale
                YLim(1) = MyChart.Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).MinimumScale
                YLim(2) = MyChart.Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).MaximumScale
                
                
                With MyChart
                    .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
                    .FullSeriesCollection(2).Name = "=""Histogram"""
                    .FullSeriesCollection(2).XValues = "='Sheet1 (2)'!$B$10:$B$16"
                    .FullSeriesCollection(2).Values = "='Sheet1 (2)'!$C$10:$C$16"
                    .FullSeriesCollection(2).AxisGroup = 2
                    .FullSeriesCollection(2).ChartType = xlColumnClustered
                    .ChartGroups(1).GapWidth = 0
                    .FullSeriesCollection(2).Format.Fill.Visible = msoFalse
                End With
```

===

I found this code online and tried it:

===

```
              Dim oSeries As Series

                For Each oSeries In MyChart.SeriesCollection
                    If oSeries.AxisGroup = xlPrimary Then
                        oSeries.AxisGroup = xlSecondary
                    Else
                        oSeries.AxisGroup = xlPrimary
                    End If
                Next oSeries`
```

===

HOWEVER, this changes the X Axis:

[Graph After Changing Y Axis - It Unintentionally Changes X Axis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j0rxi.png)

===

Slightly separate issue: I need the Y Axis labels and tick marks to be integers.

Ideas on either issue? Any assistance is appreciated!!

Best,

Dan

Comment: your problem isyour graph is using two Y axis to make the graph.  Since there is only 1 X-axis, you cannot swap the axis UNLESS the original primary and secondary axis are same or similar scale.

Comment: Thanks for the insight: Would a workaround be to set the second data series to BOTH a secondary Y axis AND a secondary X axis? Would I then be able to swap the primary and secondary Y axes?

Comment: you cant have a secondary X axis.  It does not exist in excel

Comment: what you can do is set both to the primary axis potentially, and then scale the results from one graph so that they would plot in the same range as the other graph.   That would strickly be for visual purposes though

Answer (score 0):

To solve your second question (formatting axis labels), [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Change-axis-labels-in-a-chart-1c32436b-fb12-450b-aefa-cc7e4584456a) are simple formatting instructions.

As for the first issue, if you are literally just [swapping the two Y axes](https://www.pcreview.co.uk/threads/switch-primary-and-secondary-y-axes.2953578/#post-9773191), so scale 0 to 0.005 is on the right and scale 0 to 3.5 is on the left, you'll also find that in axis options.